# Generic関数内でのFuture呼び出しの中で型Tag T が見えてない

Tags: scala

以下のコードで怒られる理由を知りたいです。
型タグは見えていると思っていました。

```
class CountDownLatch {
    var N: Int = 5
    var count: Int = 3
    def execute[T](f: => T): Future[Array[T]] = {
      def exec(): Future[T] = Future { f }

      val promise = Promise[Array[T]]()
      val future = promise.future

      // 実行開始
      Future {
        val futures = for (i <- 0 to N) yield exec().map(x => {
          println("Finished"); x
        })
        while (futures.count(ft => ft.isCompleted) >= count) {}
        promise.success(
          futures
            .filter(ft => ft.isCompleted)
            .map(ft => ft.value.get.get)
            .take(count)
            .toArray // No ClassTag Available for T と怒られる
        )
      }

      future
    }

  }
  object CountDownLatch {
    def apply(n: Int, count: Int): CountDownLatch =
      new CountDownLatch() { N = n.max(1); count = count.min(n).max(1); }
  }
```

Comment: [Arrays | Collections (Scala 2.8 - 2.12) | Scala Documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/arrays.html) の後半、"How then is Scala’s Array[T] represented?" 以降が参考になるかと思います(解決方法も記載されています)。